# Попробовать снова через определенное время WebClient

Tags: c#

Пишу парсер и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При отсутствии соединения с интернетом, программа, что логично падает, или когда сервер не вовремя отвечает.

```
public string WebsiteToString(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
                html = wc.DownloadString(url);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Проблемы с интернетом");
            }
            return html;
        }
```

Как мне в этой конструкции дописать,чтобы программа сама через минут 5 пробовала опять получить данные?

Comment: А что должна делать программа в течение этих пяти минут? И сообщение об отсутствии доступа нужно выдавать каждые 5 минут?

Comment: @VladD можно так если обрывается интернет она ждет минуту потом снова пробует если опять нет интернета опять ждет минуту и снова пробует и тд

Comment: Это я понял, а когда выдавать сообщение?

Comment: ну пусть на пятый раз выдает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
async Task<string> CheckWebsiteContentUntilSuccess(string url)
{
    const int nRetriesUntilReport = 5;
    int currentRetry = nRetriesUntilReport;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
            return wc.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (WebException) // ловить всё неправильно
        {
            currentRetry--;
            if (currentRetry == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Проблемы с интернетом");
                currentRetry = nRetriesUntilReport;
            }
        }
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажите как мне вызвать эту функцию в коде?

Comment: @shatoidil: Встречный вопрос: а что вы должны сделать с загруженным содержимым?

Comment: Передать в другой метод ,который будет парсить содержимое

Comment: @shatoidil: Окей, а когда содержимое распарсится, что должно с ним произойти?

Comment: Записываю в базу

Comment: string html = await WebsiteToString(book_node.SelectSingleNode("url").InnerText); Так выдает ошибка

Comment: Спасибо разобрался !

Comment: Окей, тогда вызов скорее всего какой-то такой: `StartParsingTask()` с `async void StartPasringTask() { var html = await CheckWebsiteContentUntilSuccess(url); await Task.Run(() => ParseAndSaveToDB(html)); }`.

Comment: @shatoidil: Пожалуйста, рад, что помогло!